# How to set the delegate of a subview

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a custom view created by subclassing UIView, and it has two UITextView subviews which are instantiated inside its init method. Let's say for clarifying things, that I have a superview A containing two UITextViews B and C.

On the other hand, I have the UIViewController VC that manages the superview A, and its responsible of its control. This means that it has the method that controls what happens when the user changes text on C.

When someone has to control a UITextView, he usually does something like

```
textView.delegate = self
```

I want to do the same, but C is not visible from VC. VC just uses A, so I have

```
a.delegate = self
```

and then I have come with the idea of doing this inside the implementation of A:

```
weak var delegate: UITextViewDelegate? {
    get {
        return c.delegate
    }

    set {
        c.delegate = newValue
    }
}
```

But this is giving me an error, saying that it's unwrapping an optional value whose actual value is nil.

So, what's the correct way of controlling UITextView C (that is inside UIView A) from VC, which only has an instance of A.

Comment: In your implementation, did you check that **c** it's not nil?

Comment: Can you expose textView C as a public property of A? Then viewController can be assigned as delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably that `c` maybe nil. To solve this, you need to set the delegate after `c` is initialised.

Alternatively, create your own delegate - `ADelegate`! This way you can name your own delegate methods with more meaningful names!

```
protocol ADelegate : class {
    func cDidChange()
}
```

In `A`:

```
weak var delegate: ADelegate?
```

Now `A` should implement `UITextViewDelegate`, set `c.delegate` to self, and relay the methods to `self.delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the `UITextField`'s in the Xcode Interface Builder, you can create outlets for the textfields in your `ViewController` (even when the textfields are sub-sub-children of the view, that the viewcontroller controls).

Thus continuing with your naming, you add the following outlets to your `ViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var B: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var C: UITextField!
```

and in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` add:

```
B.delegate = self
C.delegate = self
```

If you created the `UITextField`'s programmatically you can set their `tag` value to e.g. `1` and `2`(`0` is most likely already used) and then get the view from your `ViewController` like this:

```
let B = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField
let C = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextField
```

Of course, make sure that the `ViewController` extends `UITextFieldDelegate`, that is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {...}
```